# Characteristic polynomial of A, if $\det(\operatorname{adj}(\operatorname{adj}(A))) = 81$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a square real matrix whose eigenvalues are positive integers, with

$$\det(\operatorname{adj}(\operatorname{adj}(A))) = 81 \, .$$

What is the characteristic polynomial of A?

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Does $adj(A)$ mean the adjoint (so in the real case transpose)?

Comment: adjoint as in $Aadj(A)=det(A)I$

Comment: adj = adjugate (!= adjoint)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint.* For a $j\times j$ matrix $M$ we have
$$
\det\big(\DeclareMathOperator{adj}{adj}\adj(M)\big)=\det(M)^{j-1}
$$

Suppose $A$ is $n\times n$. Then
$$
\det\big(\adj\big(\adj(A)\big)\big)
= \det\big(\adj(A)\big)^{n-1}
= \det(A)^{(n-1)^2}
$$

Now, since the determinant of $A$ is the product of the eigenvalues of $A$ we know that $\det(A)$ is a positive integer. Thus $n$ satisfies
$$
\det(A)=81^{1/(n-1)^2}\in\Bbb N
$$
Finally, note that the characteristic polynomial is
$$
\chi_A(t)=(t-\lambda_1)\dotsb(t-\lambda_n)
$$
where $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: so $n=3$ and $det(A)=3$... but how do I get the characteristic polynomial of A?

Comment: $\det A = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3$ ($n=3$), and lambdas are integers; so, $\lambda_1 = 3$, $\lambda_2 \lambda_3 = 1$; $\lambda_2=\lambda_3=1$ or $\lambda_2=\lambda_3=-1$.

Comment: Yes,  I saw that, thanks. They are positive too, so.. 3,1,1

Comment: So the discussion says that such characteristic polynomial may be not unique

Comment: @Anjan3 What if $n=2$?